# Composite trapezoid rule not running in Octave

Tags: octave, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I have the following code in Octave for implementing the composite trapezoid rule and for some reason the function only stalls whenever I execute it in Octave on f = @(x) x^2, a = 0, b = 4, TOL = 10^-6. Whenever I call trapezoid(f, a, b, TOL), nothing happens and I have to exit the Terminal in order to do anything else in Octave. Here is the code:

```
% INPUTS
%
% f   : a function
% a   : starting point
% b   : endpoint
% TOL : tolerance

function root = trapezoid(f, a, b, TOL)
disp('test');
max_iterations = 10000;
disp(max_iterations);
count = 1;
disp(count);
initial = (b-a)*(f(b) + f(a))/2;
while count < max_iterations
disp(initial);
trap_0 = initial;
trap_1 = 0;
trap_1_midpoints = a:(0.5^count):b;
for i = 1:(length(trap_1_midpoints)-1)
    trap_1 = trap_1 + (trap_1_midpoints(i+1) - trap_1_midpoints(i))*(f(trap_1_midpoints(i+1) + f(trap_1_midpoints(i))))/2;
endfor
if abs(trap_0 - trap_1) < TOL
    root = trap_1;
    return;
endif
intial = trap_1;
count = count + 1;
disp(count);
endwhile

disp(['Process ended after ' num2str(max_iterations), ' iterations.']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your function in Matlab.
Your code is not stalling. It is rather that the size of `trap_1_midpoints` increases exponentionaly. With that the computation time of trap_1 increases also exponentionaly. This is what you experience as stalling.

I also found a possible bug in your code. I guess the line after the if clause should be `initial = trap_1`. Check the missing 'i'.

With that, your code still takes forever, but if you increase the tolerance (e.g. to a value of 1) your code return.

You could try to vectorize the for loop for speed up.

Edit: I think inside your for loop, a `)` is missing after `f(trap_1_midpoints(i+1)`.

Answer (score 0):

After `count=52` or so, the arithmetic sequence `trap_1_midpoints` is no longer representable in any meaningful fashion in floating point numbers. After `count=1075` or similar, the step size is no longer representable as a positive floating point `double` number. That all is to say, the bound `max_iterations = 10000` is ludicrous. As explained below, all computations after `count=20` are meaningless.

---

The theoretical error for stepsize `h` is `O(T·h^2)`. There is a numerical error accumulation in the summation of `O(T/h)` numbers that is of that size, i.e., `O(mu/h)` with `mu=1ulp=2^(-52)`. Which in total means that the lowest error of the numerical integration can be expected around `h=mu^(1/3)`, for double numbers thus `h=1e-5` or in the algorithm `count=17`. This may vary with interval length and how smooth or wavy the function is.

One can expect the behavior that the error divides by four while halving the step size only for step sizes above this boundary `1e-5`. This also means that `abs(trap_0 - trap_1)` is a reliable measure for the error of `trap_0` (and `abs(trap_0 - trap_1)/3` for `trap_1`) only inside this range of step sizes.

---

The error bound `TOL=1e-6` should be met for about `h=1e-3`, which corresponds to `count=10`. If the recursion does not stop for `count = 14` (which should give an error smaller than `1e-8`) then the method is not accurately implemented.